# Can we tab through the elements of bar graph in sencha 4.2 Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, wcag2.0

I have created a bar graph using Ext Js 4.2.0, I have added tabIndex property but I am unable to tab through the bars. Do we have any way to achieve the tabbing for bars in extjs. I have added tabIndex property in listener, afterrender

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['name', 'data'],
    data: [
        { 'name': 'metric one',   'data':10 },
        { 'name': 'metric two',   'data': 7 },
        { 'name': 'metric three', 'data': 5 },
        { 'name': 'metric four',  'data': 2 },
        { 'name': 'metric five',  'data':27 }
    ]
});
//create chart using extjs chart module
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    arialabel:'Sample chart',
    animate: true,
    store: store,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['data'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Sample Values',
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['name'],
        title: 'Sample Metrics'
    }],
    //Added for Tabbing
    listeners:{
        afterrender:function(c){
            var el=c.el;
        el.set({tabindex:'0','aria-label':c.arialabel});
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',
        highlight: true,
        tips: {
          trackMouse: true,
          width: 140,
          height: 28,
          renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
            this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data') + ' views');
          }
        },
        label: {
          display: 'insideEnd',
            field: 'data',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            color: '#333',
            'text-anchor': 'middle'
        },
        xField: 'name',
        yField: 'data'
    }]
});
});
```

I have created a bar graph using Ext Js 4.2.0, I have added tabIndex property but I am unable to tab through the bars. Do we have any way to achieve the tabbing for bars in extjs. I have added tabIndex property in listener, afterrender

Comment: I don't see `tabindex` anywhere in your code example.

Comment: For readability, can you put your "after render" code into your question rather than the comment section?

Comment: updated as suggested.

Comment: Ok, I see your example comes from https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Bar so I tried adding your `listeners` block to it. I dumped the `c` and `el` objects to the console to see what they were. Is the `set` method specific to an object in ExtJS? I'm familiar with sets, in general, in js (`Set()` constructor, `add()`, `delete()`, etc) but I'm not familiar with the `set()` method on an object. What object are you trying to add the `tabindex` to? It sounds like you want it on a bar but I don't think the `el` element is a bar.

Comment: And in case this isn't obvious, I'm not familiar with ExtJS but I'm curious how to get it to work. I **am** very familiar with accessibility and WCAG (which you used to tag your question). I know you can set `tabindex` on various `<svg>` elements such as a `<rect>` and that allows you to TAB to that element. But you'll also need to set a [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions), such as [`role="img"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#img), and an `aria-label` (as you alluded to). The `aria-label` will be ignored if you don't have a role.

Comment: For fun, I used the code example on cdn.sencha.com (from my earlier comment) and went into the code inspector and set `tabindex="0" aria-label="foo" role="img"` on several of the `<rect>` elements of the bar chart and I was able to TAB to them and the screen reader announced "foo, graphic".